# How can I figure out which .jar files my report is currently attempting to use?

Tags: jar, jasper-reports, ireport

I am editing a report in *iReport* that someone else has previously made and I am wondering as to how i could figure out which *.jar* files they were referencing to compile the report.

Is there a way to do this in *iReport* or am I just going to have to ask? Also- if I can figure it out where do I find a collection of *.jar* files to download and use?

There is no code with this, I'm simply trying to learn my way around *iReport*.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using iReport with java, then please download following jar files

```
mysql connector
jasperreport
itext
antlr
org.apache.commonsbeanutils
commons-digesters
org-apache-commons-logging
org-apache-commons-collections
com.springsource.org.codehaus.groovy
com.springsource.org.objectweb.asm
```

you can easily find these jar files on java2s

Comment: Could you maybe post a link to where I could download these .jar files?

Comment: please search on google and you will find all files, prefer http://www.java2s.com